# Div Wallpaper images do not show through in Opera, FF or IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html, safari, opera, banner

So my website's banner div will not display its background image in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, or IE. It works perfect in Safari, though. And In IE the divs are all aligned to the left for some reason. I've looked around a couple of sites but couldn't find much that helped me.
 My site is:
http://www.careerchat.ca/lloyd.html

Answer (score 1):

The file has a `png` extension, but is not really a `png`.  Open it again in Photoshop and make sure to save as the correct type.

```
header-wall.png: Adobe Photoshop Image, 575 x 121, RGBA, 4x 8-bit channels
```

Comment: Oh wow! That worked! Thanks a million I would have never guessed that!